# Adding 2 weeks view in Calendar ExtJs 6

Tags: javascript, extjs, calendar, sencha-touch, extjs6-classic

I want to add 2 weeks view in Calendar but so i have failed to do that. That my code so far, its not displaying the calendar giving following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: view.getView is not a function
>       at constructor.recalculate (Multi.js?_dc=20180710185310:227)...

```
{
[...]   
    day: {
        addForm: null,
        editForm: null,
        listeners: {
            eventtap: 'onEventClick',
            //click: 'onDayClick'
        }
    },
    week: {
        xtype: 'calendar-week'// This shows the one week view
    },
    weeks:{
        xtype: 'calendar-weeksview'// but this give error
    }
},
bind: {
    store: '{calendars}'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You always have to use great care with components that are two components underneath - which, like grids, are composed from one panel and one view.

`xtype: 'calendar-weeksview'` is not in the same folder as `xtype: 'calendar-week'`, while `xtype: 'calendar-weeks'` is. You may want to try that.